# How to get values from a list while calling API

Tags: c#

i am trying to call an API, to insert some values innit,but first i need to take the values from a list.My problem is in line 10, and i can't fix it.
The error is:

```
cannot convert from 'IC.xxx.logic.Data' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken?'
```

Below is the code:

```
public static void InsertRecords(List<Data> selectedData)
        {
            var access_token = xxxToken();
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.example.com/xx/v2/xxx");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Headers["Authorization"] = "xxx " + access_token;
            JObject requestBody = new JObject();
            JArray recordArray = new JArray();
            JObject recordObject = new JObject();
            10)recordObject.Add("CUSTOMER_COMPANY_NAME", selectedData[0]);
            recordObject.Add("Customer_Number",  selectedData[2]);
            recordObject.Add("Comapny_Street_1", selectedData[10]);
        }
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would suggest creating an object instance and then cast to `JObject` for ease. (Convert from an object/list to `JObject`/`JArray`)

```cs
dynamic input = new 
{
    CUSTOMER_COMPANY_NAME = selectedData[0],
    Customer_Number = selectedData[2],
    Comapny_Street_1 = selectedData[10]
};

JObject recordObject = JObject.FromObject(input);
```

Otherwise, you should provide the JSON in a string to solve the error above.

```cs
recordObject.Add("CUSTOMER_COMPANY_NAME", JObject.Parse(selectedData[0]));
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9bLfbi)

Comment: I was trying our last solution but i get an error:Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Error parsing Infinity value. Path '', line 1, position 1.'

Comment: i don't know the logic but i got it right with my solution,thank you for your time